# I get undefined as output using jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rest

I am working on developing a jQyery and i find it confusing to implement the following part. I get the result as undefined i don't what is wrong with this part

---

```
<input name="find" type="text" maxlength="400" id="find"/>
 <button onclick="find()" > Find </button>

function find()
        {
            var id = document.getElementById("find").value;
            $("#datta").html("");

            $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Fathers/" + id +"/Sons",  function(data)
            {
                for (var i in data) {
                    $('#datta').append("<p>ID: " + data.id + "</p>")
                    $('#datta').append("<p>fname: " + data.fname + "</p>")

                }});}
```

---

I have in my java Controller classes

> RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/Fathers/{fatherId}/Sons")

If i type into my browser http://localhost:8080/Fathers/1/Sons
    I get an array

> RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/Fathers/{fatherId}/Sons/{sonId}")

If i type into my browser http://localhost:8080/Fathers/1/Sons/1
    I get a single object

Father class:

```
private int id;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private Set<Son> sons = new HashSet<>();
public AppProduct(int id, String fname , String lname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;}
```

---

My Son class:

```
private int id;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private Set<Grandson> grandsons = new HashSet<>();
public AppProduct(int id, String fname , String lname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;

}
```

With my current code i get:

> ID : undefined 
>   First Name: undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for ... in` statement loops through the properties of an object, so you can not use your loop the way you want. You should use something like [jquery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$.each(data, function( key, value ) {
  $('#datta').append("<p>ID: " + value.id + "</p>")
  $('#datta').append("<p>fname: " + value.fname + "</p>")
}
```

Or a basic `for` loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   $('#datta').append("<p>ID: " + data[i].id + "</p>")
   $('#datta').append("<p>fname: " + data[i].fname + "</p>")
}
```